# How to count occurrences of a computed column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In ms sql, I try to count occurence of a computed column .

With a normal classic, no worries:

```
  SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
    FROM User
    GROUP BY ID
```

But with calculated column it display an Error

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, (ID * PI()))  AS TOTO,  COUNT(*) 
FROM User
GROUP BY TOTO
```

Do you know if there is a way to do it?

Comment: `SELECT` processed after `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this...you want to group by the same computed expression to get the count grouped by that expression

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, (ID * PI()))  AS TOTO,  COUNT(*) 
FROM User
GROUP BY CONVERT(INT, (ID * PI()))
```